# CURL unable to PUT a new DB

Tags: curl

I would like to create a new database using cURL command:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/db-name
```

Output should be `{"ok":true}`

But I get `{"error":"case_clause","reason":"{error,erofs}","ref":2230136093}`

Could you help me pls ?

Comment: Please explain a new database to what system?

Comment: I am about to work with CouchDB, but the base could be anything, it is just for training

Comment: It can’t be anything because it’s all about the database what you do and what you get back. Curl does nothing here except send a request.

Comment: I am following this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/couchdb/couchdb_creating_a_database.htm

Comment: My issue is solved (it was about docker and not curl command, my bad...). Thx for your time Sami !